# I cannot only import the module of the pygame

Tags: pygame

I recently have started the game development with python, but i got some error message every time i try to import the python module.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#here is the error
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/game.py", line 2, in <module>
  from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'
```

I'm sure that i save my game as game.py, my python version is 3.4.3 and pygame is 1.9.2. I have checked the pygame version by

```
>>>import pygame
```

and no error happens which means i have the right version?
so I cannot only import the module of the pygame. Help me please!

Comment: When you type `pygame.locals.` into the shell (before `from pygame.locals import *`), what does it auto-complete to? Any menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals as locals
from locals import *
```